Configure Playwright to avoid browser notifications (such as "this page wants to know your location")
I'm using Playwright to analyze data from a remote site. However, at the first call to
page.goto(URL)    # Initial URL

the server pops up a panel, as far as I can tell before any Javascript runs:

So far, the only solution I've found is to manually dismiss it.  This is less than ideal since it means I can't run Playwright in headless mode.
Any suggestions?

This is a browser permission notification, not a server pop up panel. Do you want to allow or block it? Is this geolocation-specific or do you want to block all browser notifications?

You can use the launchOption configuration to disable the prompt.
module.exports = {
//other playwright related configuration
  use: {
        // Browser options
        browserName: 'chromium',
        channel: 'chrome',
        headless: false,
        launchOptions: { args: ['--deny-permission-prompts'] }, //use this option to disable the prompt
       
        actionTimeout: 30 * 1000,
        navigationTimeout: 90 * 1000,
    },
}
`


Do you want to use Emulations options, specifically permissions: ['geolocation']
It is noted for phone and tablet emulation, but maybe it works in browser as well.
// playwright.config.ts

import { defineConfig } from '@playwright/test';

export default defineConfig({
  use: {
    // Emulates `'prefers-colors-scheme'` media feature.
    colorScheme: 'dark',

    // Context geolocation.
    geolocation: { longitude: 12.492507, latitude: 41.889938 },

    // Emulates the user locale.
    locale: 'en-GB',

    // Grants specified permissions to the browser context.
    permissions: ['geolocation'],

    // Emulates the user timezone.
    timezoneId: 'Europe/Paris',

    // Viewport used for all pages in the context.
    viewport: { width: 1280, height: 720 },
  },
})

Otherwise I suggest trying setting in the test itself #browser-context-grant-permissions
test('my page with location prompt', async({ page, context }) => {
   const context = this.page.context(this.browserContextOptions);
   await context.grantPermissions(['geolocation']);
   ...

